# Passing java.security.auth.login.config to Mobilefirst Patform Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

How can we pass following parameter to Mobilefirst Development Server?

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=login.config
```

I have tried adding it to jvm.options file, and it seems it is passed as parameter without effect.

Following is the code I am trying to execute, and sample of `login.config` file.

**Java code to execute in login module or adapter.**

```
LoginContext context = new LoginContext("SampleClient", new CallbackHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        NameCallback callBack = (NameCallback) callbacks[0];
        callBack.setName("EXAMPLE.COM");
    }
});
```

**login.config**

```
SampleClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    default_realm=EXAMPLE.COM;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding following code before login worked.

```
try {
    Configuration config = Configuration.getConfiguration();
    config.getAppConfigurationEntry("SampleClient");
    URIParameter uriParameter = new URIParameter(new java.net.URI("file:///path_to_your_file/login.conf"));
    Configuration instance = Configuration.getInstance("JavaLoginConfig", uriParameter);
    Configuration.setConfiguration(instance);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```